# "java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException" while starting kafka server

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I started zookeeper after that i have ran "kafka-server-start.bat mypath\server.properties" command to start kafka server.

Getting following error in kafka server window.

```
 INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/<unresolved>:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
 WARN Session 0x0 for server localhost/<unresolved>:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
 java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:149)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:157)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkRemote(SocketChannelImpl.java:815)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:837)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.registerAndConnect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:277)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.connect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:287)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1021)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1064)
```

Below are the properties in server.properties

```
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=C:\KafkaLog
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
confluent.support.metrics.enable=true
confluent.support.customer.id=anonymous
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Zookeeper properties are

```
dataDir=C:\ZookeeperLog
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=0
```

Comment: Can you include the contents of `mypath\server.properties` and `zookeeper` config files.

Comment: @SaravanakrishnanPk , edited question with server and zookeeper config files properties

Comment: @OneCricketeer ,Yes am running on windows

Comment: Please read https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Comment: Are you sure Zookeeper actually started? Specifically, /tmp doesn't exist on Windows, so the config file is incorrect

Comment: I tried by keeping specified path still facing same issue

Comment: what's the output of these command `netstat -aon | findstr '2181'` and `netstat -aon | findstr '9092'`?

Comment: Are you using any proxy / VPN apps in your system?

Comment: @SaravanakrishnanPk , i am not getting output for `netstat -aon | findstr '2181' and netstat -aon | findstr '9092' ` .

Comment: @madhuri if you are not seeing anything means `zookeeper` is not started. Start the zookeeper. Once the zookeeper started, verify it by running `netstat -aon | findstr '2181'`. Then start the `kafka` server, and verify it by running `netstat -aon | findstr '2181'`. Also share logs from command prompt for both processes.

Comment: @SaravanakrishnanPk , i am able to see processes running for "2181" port. I have started kafka server still i am facing same issue. `TCP 0.0.0.0:2181 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 15476 TCP [::]:2181 [::]:0 LISTENING 15476`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236409/discussion-between-saravanakrishnan-pk-and-madhuri).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried to check the following things in order to resolve them.

1. Updated the `dataDir` & `log.dirs` properties in config files (for matching windows platform)
2. Verified the `zookeeper` startup using `netstat -aon | findstr '2181'` command
3. Updated the `zookeeper.connect` url to `127.0.0.1:2181`
4. Added the below **Missing** loopback entries in `hosts` file and restarted the system.

`127.0.0.1  localhost`